# Generic Argument Constraint Violation?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have declared a base dialog window class that types the datacontext to ensure that the attached viewmodel has the appropriate return type. When I try to use it though I get a generic arguments error:

> GenericArguments[1],
>   'Mocks.MidSoft_Hospitality_ViewModels_Dialogs_ReceiveItemViewModel_32_569724456',
>   on
>   'Mocks.MidSoft_Hospitality_Views_Dialogs_BaseDialogWindow`2_32_569724456[TResult,TViewModel]'
>   violates the constraint of type 'TViewModel'.

I can't see why this would be happening

The base dialog window declaration:

```
public class BaseDialogWindow<TResult, TViewModel> : DialogWindowBase<TResult> where TViewModel: ViewModels.Dialogs.DialogBaseViewModel<TResult>
{
    public BaseDialogWindow() : base()
    {

    }

    new public TViewModel DataContext
    {
        get => this.GetValue(DataContextProperty) as TViewModel;
        set => this.SetValue(DataContextProperty, value);
    }

}
```

DialogWindowBase:

```
public class DialogWindowBase<TResult> : Window, IDialog<TResult>
{
    public DialogWindowBase()
    {
        //Formatting code here
    }

    public Result Result { get; set; } = Result.None;

    public TResult ReturnData { get; set; }

}
```

The viewModel:

```
public class ReceiveItemViewModel : ViewModels.Dialogs.DialogBaseViewModel<ReceiveItemResult>
{
    //View Model Code here
}
```

and the xaml:

```
<local:BaseDialogWindow x:Class="MidSoft.Hospitality.Views.Dialogs.ReceiveItemDialog"
                        x:TypeArguments="local:ReceiveItemResult, vm:ReceiveItemViewModel"
                        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MidSoft.Hospitality.ViewModels.Dialogs"
                        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MidSoft.Hospitality.Views.Dialogs"
                        mc:Ignorable="d"
                        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:ReceiveItemViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
                        x:Name="ReceiveStockItemDialog"
                        Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</local:BaseDialogWindow>
```

Code for the dialog:

```
    public partial class ReceiveItemDialog
    {
        public ReceiveItemDialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

The error that I referenced above is the only compiler error that I am getting. I would appreciate any insight into this error.

Update: I have now noticed that the application is compiling and running without any exceptions being thrown but the error is still there and the xaml designer is showing it as invalid markup

Comment: Why do you need to override `DataContext` and set it to class, which inherits `Window`?

Comment: `IsDesignTimeCreatable=False` will force the designer to ignore the specified `DesignInstance` type and create a substitute type using reflection. It failed to recognize the generic type as it is a complex type rather than a primitive type and therefore failed to create a proper mock instance with a proper generic parameter  `TViewModel`.

Comment: You could set the `IsDesignTimeCreatable` property to `True` and implement a default constructor on `ReceiveItemViewModel` or if a default constructor is not possible, introduce a wrapper type just for the design time `DesignInstance` and spend it a a default constructor that initializes the base type `ReceiveItemViewModel` properly.

Comment: @BionicCode I add the the default constructor as suggested and set IsDesignTimeCreatable to true but the error still persists

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski The overriding of the datacontext is purely to ensure that the viewmodel complies with the constraint on the returntype. The class it is overridden to does not inherit window

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly set the type? e.g. `d:DesignInstance {x:Type vm:ReceiveItemViewModel}` or  `d:DesignInstance Type=vm:ReceiveItemViewModel`. Maybe the type converter that converts the `string` to a type fails.

Comment: @BionicCode I think this is a problem with the IDE. I made the change you suggested but the error persisted. I opened the exact same code up in Blend and it showed no errors

Comment: Alright but it was throwing an exception before. Can you verify that setting `IsDesignTimeCreatable=True` and adding a default constructor fixed the problem, please?

Comment: @BionicCode Yes - if you give this as the answer I will accept it

Comment: I was just curious. But I can add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IsDesignTimeCreatable=False` will force the designer to ignore the specified `DesignInstance` type and create a substitute type using reflection. In this case the designer failed to recognize the generic type as it is a complex type rather than a primitive type and therefore failed to create a proper mock instance with a proper generic parameter `TViewModel`.

To solve this, you could set the `IsDesignTimeCreatable` property to `True` and implement a default constructor on `ReceiveItemViewModel`. If a default constructor is not possible, introduce a wrapper type just for the design time `DesignInstance` and spend it a a default constructor that initializes the base type `ReceiveItemViewModel` properly.